# Probabilities of the different fission reactions in U-235

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have found out that the 3 main fission reactions in U-235 are given as:

U-235 + n ===> Ba-144 + Kr-90 + 2n + Q (about 200 MeV)

U-235 + n ===> Ba-141 + Kr-92 + 3n + Q (170 MeV)

U-235 + n ===> Zr-94 + Te-139 + 3n + Q (197 MeV).

My question is, that i want to find out how probable these fission reactions are, since i want to find the average of the amount of MeV produced. Many sites state that the average is around 200 MeV, which doesn't make sense to me unless the first reaction given above stands for an abruptly large amount of the reactions.
I also cant seem to figure out how the different reactions happen, is it just at random that, say the 3rd reaction happens, or are there some preliminary events that leads up to the different reactions?

Comment: There are many many fission paths. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205620/ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many 235U fission reactions here : see Todd Koelsch thesis :

https://esirc.emporia.edu/bitstream/handle/123456789/3523/Todd%20Koelsch%20Spring%2016.pdf?sequence=1